# Bash detect an error in loop then continue processing

Tags: bash

I would like to process a list of Homebrew formulas contained in a text file.  If there is an installation error (e.g. already install, bad formula name), I'd like it to write the error, but continue processing.  The [Github project](https://github.com/craibuc/brewer).

What I have so far:

```
...
# process list of formulas that have been installed
for i in $(cat $FILE) ; do

    echo "Installing $i ..."

    # attempt to install formula; if error write error, process next formula

    brew install $i

done
...
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What happens with the current script?

Comment: After the brew command, the very next line, add this: if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then continue; fi or say brew something || continue. You should look into "trap" command as well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does it help?

```
...
# process list of formulas that have been installed
for i in $(< "$FILE") ; do

    echo "Installing $i ..."

    # attempt to install formula; if error write error, process next formula

    brew install "$i" || continue

done
...
```

Note that if formula contains blanks then the `for` loop will split the line. It might be better to write:

```
...
# process list of formulas that have been installed
while read i ;  do

    # Jump blank lines
    test -z "$i" && continue

    echo "Installing $i ..."

    # attempt to install formula; if error write error, process next formula

    brew install "$i" || continue

done < "$FILE"
...
```

Comment: The second option attempted to process the file's blank lines.  Opted for the first.

Answer (score 6):

That should be simple.

```
# process list of formulas that have been installed
for i in $(<"$FILE") ; do

    echo "Installing $i ..."

    # attempt to install formula; if error write error, process next formula

    if ! brew install $i
    then
        echo "Failed to install $i"
        continue
    fi

done
```

Adding an `if` statement to the installation part will check for the exit status of `brew` and if it failed then will report and error and continue.

Comment: I like the flexibility of adding a custom error message, but `brew`'s failure message is adequate.